# HIve: unable create partition on already created table which consists of data

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning

HIVE:

i have created a table and i loaded the data(1GB) into that table...while creating the table i didn't mentioned the partitioned column's.

```
Now i want create 10 partition's on the same table with already loaded data(1GB).
```

Could any body please give me a solution for this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The concept of partition is to handle data ,  which cannot be created after you load data. It has to be defined in your DDL beforehand.

I suggest , you drop  the table and create a new table with mentioning partitions.